# Bash replace string with variable value

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script to replace a string in `AndroidManifest.xml` with additional permissions defined in a variable, but I'm failing with the pattern definition.

All examples I found use simple replace strings without any special characters like in this case.

This is what I tried so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CUSTOMPERMISSION=android.permission.INTERNET,android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

echo $CUSTOMPERMISSION
printf "\n"
IFS=','

read -a permissionArray <<< $CUSTOMPERMISSION

printf "There are ${#permissionArray[*]} words in the text.\n\n"

ADDME=""
# Print each value of the array by using the loop
for (( n=0; n < ${#permissionArray[@]}; n++))
do
  ADDME+="<uses-permission android:name=\"${permissionArray[n]}\"/>\n"
done

printf "$ADDME"

REPLACE="<!-- custom_permisions -->"

perl -pe 's/'"${REPLACE}"'/'"${ADDME}"'/' -i AndroidManifest.xml
#sed -i "s/<!-- custom_permisions -->/"${ADDME}"/g" AndroidManifest.xml
```

I'd like to keep the format of `ADDME` with a new line so the formatting stays in place.
I tried to add `\` for `<` and `-` trying to escape them since the script fails with

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "n<"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm not sure where I go wrong, I keep going in circles with search results, so I hoped someone would know the answer.

Comment: `perl -pe` use an XML aware tool to edit XML files.

Comment: Not sure that's the issue, I tried both `perl` and `sed` and both work if I use simple strings, so I assume the issue is in the formatting.

Comment: The issue with your code is that word splitting is performed on unquoted results of expansions, so because `${RESPLACE}` is unquoted and contains spaces it is spitted on space. Please use http://shellcheck.net and fix basic mistakes.

Comment: I updated the script after the checks, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: .... Because you have `/` in the `ADDME`. Replace it with `\/`

Comment: You using ```printf``` for simple output instead of ```echo```. Then try with ```printf``` to format your ```${ADDME}``` Example: ```ADDME=$(printf "\'\${%s}\'" 'USER')```

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands

```
REPLACE='<\!-- custom_permisions -->'
CUSTOMPERMISSION=android.permission.INTERNET,android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
ADDME=$(printf '<uses-permission android:name=\\"%s\\"\\/>\\n' ${CUSTOMPERMISSION//,/ })
ADDME=${ADDME%\\n*}
sed "s|$REPLACE|$ADDME|g" AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it was solved in the comments on the question.